# Why can't I download my data from Heroku?

Tags: sqlite, heroku, git-clone

I have a django web app deployed on Heroku.  My local environment uses sqlite3.  I can add data on the local environment and push it to Heroku - that's no problem.  The trouble is if data is added to the database on the live environment, which seems to be using Postgres, I cannot subsequently update my local db with live data.

I have tried cloning from Heroku but the cloned database does not contain the latest data added on live.  It only contains data pushed from local before data was subsequently added on the live environment.  I'm new to this and don't understand why cloning doesn't result in the latest data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a few problems here, but the central one is that you're committing data to your database and trying to move it around between environments. That shouldn't be part of any regular workflow. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: (The other major issue is that SQLite isn't compatible with Heroku's ephemeral filesystem; once I understand [what you're really trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627) I can write an answer that addresses both issues.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I am developing at the moment and deploying new code to live after testing on my local machine but when I do, the live data is overwritten by my local data, which may not be the same.  I was then trying to bring the live data to my local machine so that when I continue to develop and push to live, I am not overwriting live data.  Apart from perhaps converting my local database to postgres, I should somehow be avoiding pushing the local database to live.

Comment: Yes, you should avoid pushing your database. Are you using schema migrations?

Comment: I don't know what that is, really.  I understand database schemes but not sure about schema migrations.  I'm trying to convert to postgress now...

Comment: Are you using a framework of some kind? Or a database abstraction layer, like an ORM?

Comment: I'm using django as the framework.  I did a bit more research and think perhaps going with postgress on AWS or similar for the database and static content.